# How would Zeus(load balancer) handle the closed connection

Tags: jetty, load-balancing, zeus

Currently, we run into one problem with timeout issue. Our application is based on Jetty and uses Zeus as load balancing. The maxIdleTime is set as default value 30000 in jetty.xml. When a request/connection exceeds 30 seconds, the connection status will change to TIME_WAIT, but we get the HTTP 500 Internal Error in the browser side.

I guess the HTTP 500 error comes from Zeus but I want to confirm this: how would Zeus handle the closed connection?
OR
The jetty service sends 500 to Zeus? If so, how can I confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The surefire way to iron out what is happening here is to sniff the packets using something like ethereal or tcpdump between the load balancer and the jetty server, and you can use the network tooling in something like firebug or the chrome developer tools to see what is happening on that side of the connection.  You can also turn on debug on the jetty side to see what it is doing specifically.

Regardless, if your hitting your timeout settings then you need to either increase those settings or decided on a proper strategy to deal with them to avoid this sort of issue, assuming you don't want that 500 error on the browser.